# Adding a scrollbar to a Tkinter canvas object

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

After looking for some assistance for help to adding a scroll bar to a canvas frame I seem to have cobbled something together. This however, doesn't seem to "join" the output I packed to the canvas with the scrollbar. A scrollbar appears but it is "full" so doesn't scroll and isn't actually connected/joined with the displayed output.

```
root = Tkinter.Tk()

sizex = 1050
sizey = 800
posx = 100
posy = 100
root.wm_geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (sizex, sizey, posx, posy))

myframe = Frame(root, relief=GROOVE, width=50, height=100, bd=1)
myframe.place(x=10,y=10)

canvas=Canvas(myframe)
frame=Frame(canvas)
myscrollbar = Scrollbar(myframe, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=myscrollbar.set)

myscrollbar.pack(side="right", fill="y")
canvas.pack(side="left")
canvas.create_window((0,0), window=frame, anchor='nw')

def myfunction(event):
 canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"),width=sizex,height=sizey)

frame.bind("<Configure>", myfunction)

data = information.read()

L1 = Label(root, text = 'A Title')
L1.pack(side=TOP)

text = Text(root)
text.insert(INSERT, data)
text.pack()
```

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you are "packing something to the canvas".

Comment: @BryanOakley   Ok, I have the section text.pack(). It appears on the original canvas that I am attempting to add a scrollbar to so it's not like it never appears. Could you provide some additional information as to what I am missing?

Comment: If you pack something in the canvas, it won't scroll. Only thing that scrolls are canvas items, not widgets added via `pack`, `place`, or `grid`

Comment: @BryanOakley What should I be doing instead? This was largely adapted from a suggestion with someone using grid, and the comments had said it would work with things other than grid like pack.